# How to Display Image in header using react-native-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using **react-native-navigation**'s startTabBasedApp component to build my tabs. In my Home tab I need to show one image/logo to the left of title. I have given my code below.

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
   tabs: [
      {
      label: "Home",
      title: "Home",
      screen: "awesome-Navigation.FindPlace",
      icon: sources[0], //from my source obj
      navigatorStyle: {
        navBarBackgroundColor: '#535492',
        navBarTextColor: 'white'
      }
     //is there any way to add image using navigationoptions inside this??
     ]

    })
```

Comment: As far as I know, you have to set up a custom component for that. But I may be wrong

Comment: I there any build in property to display image in header??

Comment: You can use header property in navigationOptions and give a custom component in that property.

Comment: For example to show a icon in the left of screen I use. static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginPage', { index: 1 })}><Icon name='navigate-before' style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} size={40} color={'white'} /></TouchableOpacity>)
  });

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabIcon` property

```
navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'Contact Us',
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#191565' },
            headerTintColor: '#FFF',
            tabBarIcon:(<Icon name='navigate-before'  size={40} color={'white'} />)

        }
```

and in the `tabBarOptions` Below enable the

set  `showIcon:true`

and set `flexDirection` of the tabStyle to `row`

```
tabStyle: {
          flexDirection:'row'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use headerLeft inside your screen component. headerLeft has to be declared inside navigationOptions:

```
class ScreenComponent extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = () => {
      return {
         headerLeft: <MaterialIcons .... /> // --> Your Icon
      }
   }

  ...
}
```